# how to use the imagemin buffer function

Tags: node.js, imagemin

I'm trying to use the imagemin buffer function:
https://github.com/imagemin/imagemin

```
 file.on('data', function (d) {
   fileBuffer = Buffer.concat([fileBuffer, d]);
 }).on('end', function () {
   imagemin.buffer(fileBuffer, {
       plugins: [
          imageminMozjpeg(),
          imageminPngquant({quality: '80'})
       ]
     }).then(function (file) {
       console.log(file);
     }, function (err) {
       console.dir(err);
     });
```

for some reason its not working. does anyone know why?

Answer (score 2):

*imagemin.buffer* function works right, but you can have problem with **end** event. I believe your function has never been called.

Below you can see example with *bluebird* modification.

```
const imagemin = require('imagemin');
const Promise = require('bluebird');

Promise.promisify(fs.readFile)('./screenshot.png')
  .then(buffer => {
    return imagemin.buffer(buffer, {
      plugins: [
          imageminMozjpeg(),
          imageminPngquant({quality: '80'})
      ]
    })
  })
  .then(outBuffer => {
    console.log(outBuffer.length);
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
  })
```